# Grails preserving flash message between redirects

Tags: flash, grails

In grails, if I do something like this:

```
def someAction() {
 //.......

 flash.message = "some message"
 [:]
}
```

Then in someAction.gsp, it would display the flash message.

But if its something like this:

```
def someAction() {
 // ......
 flash.message = "some message"

 redirect uri: "${createLink(controller: 'someothercontroller', action: 'someotheraction')}"
}
```

Then in above case, in someotheraction.gsp will not have the flash.message.

My question is how do I pass on `flash.message` from someAction to someotheraction (possibly in someothercontroller or same controller).

I know I can do something like `params.flash = flash.message` and in the other action use this params.flash to assign to `flash.message` there. However in this approach, I must always know all the possible redirects which may not always happen.

So is there a better and maybe a 'standard' way to preserve the flash message till the very last redirect(that renders gsp finally)?

Answer (score 1):

"There's a plugin for that!"

Unfortunately an old one, but either it still works or you can browse the source code for inspiration. It's based on saving the message in the session, as proposed by another answer.

[One-Time Data plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/one-time-data)

Answer (score 1):

Grails preserves flash between redirects, here is an example:

```
class ExampleController {
  def action1() {
    flash.message = 'test'
    redirect action: 'action2'
    // or redirect uri: "${createLink(controller: 'example', action: 'action2')}" or any other ways
    return
  }

  def action2() {
    render text: flash.message
  }
}
```

Works perfectly and renders `'test'` in action2. Maybe you have several redirects? In this case you should re-define your flash message before next redirect.

**UPD:**

Using session (simple but not bulletproof):

```
class ExampleController {
  def action1() {
    session.message = 'text'
    redirect action: 'action2'
  }

  def action2() {
    def msg = session?.message
    session.message = ''

    render text: msg
  }
}
```

A little better way for serveral simultanious requests from one user (session_id), but not ideal also:

```
class ExampleController {
  def action1() {
    session.messages = (session.messages?:[]) + ['text']
    redirect action: 'action2'
  }

  def action2() {
    def msg = flash.messages?.get(0)
    flash.messages?.remove(0)

    render text: msg
  }
}
```

This is just an idea, maybe you will find out a better way with `session`.

Comment: Yeah I got multiple redirects. I was looking a way to achieve what I want without having to redefine flash messages because all redirects might not be obvious in all scenarios and some of them may even not be under our control(e.g. that thru a plugin)

Comment: In this case flash is not suitable for you. Use session instead of flash. But don't remember to erase it after reading in the last action. Also, there may be a situation with the wrong message when a user with a single session_id opens multiple windows at the same time (but this is unlikely).

Comment: @rahulserver what kind of solution did you end up with?

Comment: That was exactly my issue, I was redirecting over two stops. I chose a direct redirect, and now it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried that some time, but you can't do that, maybe you should save the message in session, something like:

```
session.message = "your message"
```

Then you will have that message where you need it.

Comment: But then the message stays in the entire session.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you need, if you want to preserve the message you should save it in session and eliminate it when you know you won't need it again. But if you want the flash.message be available just after using one redirect, it works fine but use redirect in this way: redirect (controller: 'someothercontroller', action: 'someotheraction'). I would like to know why the negative point, the way you make the question it looks like you want to preserve the message through many redirects, not just one.

Comment: Adding to this method, you should have a taglib that prints the message and also removes it from session after it's printed, then it's the most reliable method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def someAction(){
    flash.message = "some message"
    redirect action: 'anotherAction'
}

def anotherAction() {
    flash.message = flash.message
}
```